# Selenium webdriver code doesnt work the same way all the time

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium webdriver code.Issue is the first time it runs successfully. when i run the same code second time it doesnt work and give errors. Behavior is not as expected all the time. I am working in IE browser. Please let me know what is the cause for this.

Comment: Please post the code, error and what you have tried. Without it, the question you posted would be meaningless and might not get an reasonable answer.

Comment: Could be lots of things such as cached content or states, cookies, sessions, etc. You need to give more details. Do you ensure a clean session between each run?

Comment: Thanks lensman. Yes i want to ensure a clean session each time i run my code. It should work the same way all the time.Please let me know any solution on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a C#/NUnit framework and set the InternetExplorerOptions() as part of the [SetUp].
Here is an example of how to use the IE options to use EnsureCleanSession:

```
//Create Internet Explorer Options
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
```

Also it is best to start each test in a new window, so be sure to use driver.Quit() at the end of each test to close all existing windows so the next test will start in a fresh window.

Comment: Thanks Lensman. can you please let me know how it is done in Java. I am using java code in IE8.

Comment: Here's the link to the WebDriver Java docs: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

I think the bit you need is: 
IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION
public static final java.lang.String IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION
Capability that defines to clean or not browser cache before launching IE by IEDriverServer.